# Give rank using field values on table in Talend

Tags: talend

Right Now, I have 8 tables that needs to transform into 1, and I need to add Rank to the Output Table.

By using, Amount Collected field from 1 of the 8 table.

Sample:
      Table A: amount_assignment

```
  Table B: amount_collected

  OutputTable: Rank= 1 (based on the highest collected)
```

How can I place 1, 2, 3.... on the Output Table field Rank based on the computed 'amount_collected'?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use your inputdataflow-->tSortRow-->tMap. In tSortrow you can sort data based on amount column you need and then further in tMap you can put a sequence number to every row using Numeric.sequence("sequencename",1,1) in expression for rank_column